# class method weirdness (PHP)

Tags: php

I encountered a class which has the following method:

```
class Period
{
/** @var \DateTime */
public $startDate;

/** @var \DateTime */
public $endDate;

public static function create(DateTime $startDate, $endDate): Period
{
    return new static($startDate, $endDate);
}
}
```

My question is about the part after the create(...) - the ": Period". I have never seen this before and can't find any documentation about it (mainly because I have no clue what to look for). Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is new in PHP version 7 and above. It's called return type declarations.
In the example you posted it requires the method `create` to return an object of `Period`.

An easier example would be:

```
function giveMeAnInt() : int {
    return 1;
}
```

Above code is valid because it returns an integer.

```
function giveMeAnInt() : int {
    return "Hello";
}
```

This is not valid and will return a fatal error "FATAL ERROR Uncaught TypeError: Return value of giveMeAnInt() must be of the type integer, string returned"

Comment: That would make sense. I'll tag this as the correct answer. Thanks!

Comment: just to add, [here](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/return_types) is the full RFC on it.

Answer (score 1):

looks like this code belongs to time range api for php (class) , for more informations http://period.thephpleague.com/

Example : to create a new instance representing a given week :

```
<?php

public static Period::createFromWeek(int $year, int $week): Period
...
```

The **$year** parameter must be a valid year;
The **$week** parameter must be a valid week (between 1 and 53);

more examples here : http://period.thephpleague.com/examples/